# Block helpers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I looked around a bit about block helpers in rails but I got even more confused than what I had began with.
My objective is to create a helper like this

```
<% needs_clearance 1 do %>
    You'll see this block if your clearance is level 1, 4 or 5
<% end %>
```

which should yield

```
 <% if current_user.clearance.id == 1 or current_user.clearance_id == 4 or current_user.clearance.id == 5 %>
     You'll see this block if your clearance is level 1, 4 or 5
 <% end %>
```

4 and 5 being Management and Admin roles respectively.
How do I create this block helper?

Comment: What's the specific issue? You should just be able to do your logic and `capture` the results of your block?

Comment: I really didnt understand how to build a block helper, and I couldnt find an example which I could use as a guideline. I was hoping someone could post a helper that would yield what I wanted so I could use it as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly:

```
def needs_clearance(level, &block)
  if current_user.clearance >= level
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

Block helpers generally look like the following, e.g., to wrap something in a div:

```
def box(&block)
  "<div class='box'>" + capture(&block) + "</div>"
end
```

From: http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3

I'd consider reading that, too, as it discusses an interesting consequence of block helpers.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks!